# Gatling Recorder: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: gatling

I am pretty new to Gatling.
I have Windows 8.1 and Symantec Endpoint Protection installed on my office PC. While trying record a simple login scenario for one my client's site, I am always confronted with this error. Had search Gatling Google Group and found a November 2012 post but could not make much out of it. Please help.

I have tested with Symantec Endpoint Protection enabled and disabled both, but for the same result.

```
C:\Users\Asheesh\Downloads\gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.3\bin>Recorder.bat
GATLING_HOME is set to "C:\Users\Asheesh\Downloads\gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.3"
Jan 05, 2015 6:48:49 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler
WARNING: EXCEPTION, please implement io.gatling.recorder.http.handler.remote.RemoteHandler.exceptionCaught() for proper handling.
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Does this happen only with a given application/website, or with all of them?

Comment: Hi Stephane, I tried over 3 sites and all of them produced the same error at some or the other page. One of the sites produced it on the Home Page itself. Other one produced it when I tried to Login after entering valid credentials. Yet another produced it when I logged in and tried to search for some items. The sites that I am trying to stress test are all eCommerce sites. Thanks

Comment: Do you reach those directly? Or do you have to go through a proxy?

Comment: The sites are QA sites hosted on remote servers. I have to make entries in HOSTS file for the URLs before navigating to them. On my system, i have tested multiple times via Firefox (after setting the 'Manual Proxy Configuration' (localhost and 8181)) and Chrome (Internet Settings - > LAN Settings -> Use Proxy Server -> Address:localhost; Port:8181). Kept port 8181 for https/ https in Gatling's Recorder as well.

Comment: Does this happen over HTTP or HTTPS only?

Comment: Also, which JDK version do you use?

Comment: For the first question, i have observed it over HTTP (though i am not sure about https, reason being when i run recorder.bat and then load the site in firefox, i am taken to the site; but when i repeat the same process with Chrome, i am asked if i wish to browse the untrusted content, and them some certificate error is shown and it is only after i accept 'continuing with untrusted content' does it let me browse to the URL. When i am not running 'Recorder.bat' (and no proxy on my system), on loading the same URL in Chrome, not warning related to 'untrusted site/ content' is shown.

Comment: For the second question, I have 64 bit JDK7.

Comment: No, I'd like the exact version. Which update? What do you get when you run java -version?

Comment: Hi
Java version on my system is:

java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: I opened an issue (https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2492). Sadly won't be able to investigate for now.